# Como aprender orientação a objetos corretamente?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Muito do código "OO" que se vê por aí é procedural. Eu por exemplo já cometi e continuo cometendo vários "pecados" por dia programando OO.

O paradigma não é fácil de aprender e leva tempo, enquanto isso vários erros são cometidos e a manutibilidade do código sofre. Quando sai da faculdade você é só um criador de caos, que com o tempo pode desenvolver a capacidade de criar e recuperar a ordem nos projetos em que se envolve.

Mas se a receita do bolo estivesse disponível...

Ela existe? Se existe, qual é?

No que consistiria um estudo de OO bem dirigido?

Por exemplo, no meu aprendizado me fez muita falta conhecer a substituição de Liskov. *Tell don't ask* também foi um abridor de mentes (criar *getters* somente onde necessário e mandar o objeto executar a ação em vez de pedir para ele as informações necessárias e executar do lado de fora). Padrões de projeto estou conhecendo aos poucos, e estou estudando UML também (já que não há livro de A&POO que não a aplique). Toda a técnica de criar modelos de domínio é interessante porque me ajuda a escolher os objetos corretos a serem colocados no domínio em vez de ficar inventando abstrações aleatórias. Outras coisas são importantes também, coesão, acoplamento.

Essas são "ciladas" que eu gostaria de ter evitado, se me tivessem sido passadas previamente. Por isso a pergunta.

Ou largar tudo isso e ir vender coco na praia? (pergunta retórica :).

**EDIT**: Alterei a pergunta para torná-la mais objetiva, mas sem mexer muito no conteúdo original.

Comment: Para aprender POO puro e tradicional? Eu recomendo fugir de 3 da lista: padrões de projeto e UML. Padrões de projeto porque isso é algo que primeiro é adequado sentir a necessidade (logo, precisa ter maturidade no assunto). UML porque é algo mais focado em documentação da engenharia, não na construção propriamente dita. E também porque eu acho particularmente inútil ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Coloquei UML porque serve para analisar o design individualmente e para discutir o design em grupos. E porque é muito difícil ver um livro de APOO que não aplique UML. Mas realmente não é uma coisa que se vê usando forte no mercado.

Comment: Entendo que a pergunta pode ser baseada em opinião. Mas tem três upvotes já. :) não poderia ser melhorada? O que quero saber é no que focar quando se está aprendendo OO para evitar cometer erros no aprendizado. Ou a única opção é aprender apanhando com esses erros? É custoso, deve ter uma opção melhor.

Comment: Já vi alguns relatos de programadores/tutores de programadores falando que, mesmo quando se trata de uma equipe de linguagem de alto nível (como Java ou Ruby ou Python), aqueles membros da equipe que tiveram contato com C no começo dos estudos se dava melhor por ter feito muitos erros durante os estudos e aprendido a evitá-los de tanto se calejar. Por exemplo, Michale Feathers [cita isso](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/testing-yourself-growing-refactoring-michael-feathers/)

Comment: Mesmo assim algumas coisas podem ser ensinadas para evitar esses calos, por exemplo substituição de Liskov, como modelar o domínio corretamente, preferir composição a herança, padrões GRASP, coesão, acoplamento... mas entendo seu ponto. Além disso, você cita o C, que é procedural, sendo que os erros em OO são o que eu gostaria de evitar.

Comment: Sobre o "tell-dont-ask", pelo próprio Martin Fowler: "For me, [...] I don't find it [tell-dont-ask] a point worth highlighting"

Comment: Não teve jeito, era opinativa demais e acabei ajudando a fechar. Fica para a próxima...